# How to clone entire repo using eGit?

Tags: android, git, manifest, egit, repo

I am new to GIT. I have a manifest file that contains group of related projects. I installed eGIT eclipse plugin to clone the projects. I am able to clone projects one by one in the manifest file. But I want all the projects in my manifest file to by clone at a single time for a specific branch.

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="ssh://xyz.com:29418/" name="origin" review="xyz.com:8081"/>

  <default remote="origin" revision="refs/heads/evo_main" sync-j="4"/>

  <project groups="common" name="ACT.git" path="code/ACT"/>
  <project groups="common" name="AppEngine.git" path="code/AppEngine"/>
  .
  .
  .
  .



</manifest>
```

I am able to clone a single project with the url

```
ssh://user@xyz.com:29418/ACT.git
```

But since there are lot of projects I need a way to download all in a single clone. I dont want to use GitBash or any other command line tools. I want to achieve this eclipse plugins. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write script that does it for you or to use external program like 
[mr](http://myrepos.branchable.com/)

The above [mr](http://myrepos.branchable.com/) is a software that know how to handle sereveral repository types.

If you dont use anything like that you will have to write script that does something like:

```
- run on every folder in a given path (or give it a list of paths)
- verify that each folder is a git repository (has .git folder inside)
- execute your git command (like git fetch --all --prune or git pull ...)
```

Comment: What kind of script.. can you please elaborate?